# Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in GAS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-apps-script

I am sending an (HTTP GET) $.ajax request (from jsfiddle) to my Google Apps Script server and I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://script.google.com/macros/s/mykey?params.
>
> Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I have successfully implemented jsonp $.ajax requests to retrieve json data and javascript using this GAS/jsfiddle configuration. However, I seem unable to accomplish this jsonp success this time. Possibly because I am going through an .updaterow() function (per jqWidgets?)

My research:

1. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains) almost asks a similar question except it is not specific to GAS.
2. I do not think GAS allows one to set server-side response headers. But surely there must be a way to get my request to execute?
3. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481222/how-do-i-make-xhr-ajax-requests-against-google-apps-script-contentservice-work) explains it better? ([GAS issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1563)) Is there a workaround solution? (Come on creative people.)

Comment: if you can't set the server-side response headers, then it isn't possible to get said data other than with jsonp or a proxy.

Comment: When I try jsonp, I get an error that just says, Status: cancelled. and Type: pending. I have no idea what that means or why I get it. (Per chrome developer tools.)

Comment: I have no idea either. I haven't encountered that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481222/how-do-i-make-xhr-ajax-requests-against-google-apps-script-contentservice-work <-- This question perhaps explains it better? (See item#3 in last paragraph of question if you can not view the link. I edited the original question to include that link.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAS does not allow CORS headers at this time.