# Can I fire an Ajax request to Google Apps Script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-apps-script

I want to have a static page (HTML/CSS/JavaScript (jQuery)) that fires an Ajax request to Google Apps Script so that it can return a list of Google Docs, then the JavaScript can display that its, have the user select a document and fire another Ajax request to get the content of the document. The JS is going to be specific to the page and I will write it myself, but I need to know if Google Apps Script can be always open to receive these HTTP requests. It looks like I have to have a trigger, meaning it can't always be available. Is there any way to have Google Apps Script always be available to receive and respond to HTTP requests?

Comment: if you launch your google app script as a web app, then why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a GET request to a published script using the content service parameters.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content

Answer (score -1):

It can receive POST and GET requests, you gotta use a doGet() or doPost() to get its parameters. Check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) out

If you have problems with Ajax requests check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481222/how-do-i-make-xhr-ajax-requests-against-google-apps-script-contentservice-work/42149647#42149647).