# Using google.visualization.Query in google web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a functioning google web app that is identical to the app presented [here]

You'll note in code.gs that SpreadsheetApp.openByID......getRange().getValues() is used to retrieve an Array that is later converted into a DataTable in the Dashboard-JavaScript.html

Working Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Dashboard demo')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
/**
 * Return all data from first spreadsheet as an array. Can be used
 * via google.script.run to get data without requiring publication
 * of spreadsheet.
 * Returns null if spreadsheet does not contain more than one row.
 */
function getSpreadsheetData() {
  var sheetId = '-key-';  
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:D8").getValues();
  return (data.length > 1) ? data : null;
}
```

I would like to use google.visualization.query instead of .getRange.

Does not work - currently returns "Google" not defined

```
    function doGet(e) {
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
   // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
      return template.evaluate()
          .setTitle('Dashboard demo')
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    }

    function getSpreadsheetData() {

      var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
      var sheetId = '-key-';
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com?key=' + sheetId, opts);
        query.setQuery('select A, B, C, D');
        query.send(draw)


    }
    function draw(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
              alert('Error in query');
            }
      alert('No error')
    }
```

I'm certain there are several issues - but I can't get any helpful errors returned to debug the issue.

My questions are:

1. Is is possible to use google.visualization.query in code.gs? 
   *(I've read a post that leads me to believe that perhaps it cannot be used server side??/why)*
2. If yes - how do I avoid "google not defined" errors
3. If no - is there an alternative method to "query" a google sheet from server side (the end goal is to have the flexibility to omit columns, perform aggregate functions, etc. when the datatable is retrieved).  It is not possible to change the underlying spreadsheet (ie. sharing and publishing)

Finally- I apologize if any of this is formatted poorly or not clear.  This is my first post here.  In addition, I have limited experience and less expertise with javascript/apps script and google web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot be done server side, because `google` is a client side API. 
Same reason as with `google.script.run`. (For a better understanding, you can check the whole code yourself, it resides [here](https://www.google.com/jsapi), a code that needs to be embedded within `<script>` tags, on the `Html` side).

As an alternative for the server side, you should be able to use the [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

The URL to compose should look something like:

```
var BASE_URL = "https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/";
var SS_KEY = "stringSS_Key";
var BASE_QUERY = "/gviz/tq?tq=";
var partialUrl = BASE_URL + SS_KEY + BASE_QUERY;
var queryToRun = 'select dept, sum(salary) group by dept';
var finalUrl = partialUrl + encodeURIComponent(queryToRun);
```

And call `URLFetchApp.fetch` on it.

Comment: Based on what I've read elsewhere - URLFetchApp requests are not executed in the context of the server side code.  Therefore I believe the sheet would need to be "published" or shared with everyone to function.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725424/content-service-for-google-apps-script-returning-html-instead-of-json

Comment: You need auth, yes, but google provides apps for that as well. So either you use URLFetchApp or, my recommandation, you move your query on client side (will be both easier and cleaner)

Comment: Would I not also need to specify a tab (aka sheet within a google sheet) I believe usually "gid=0" for the first tab.  Where would that land in the URL builder you've constructed?

Comment: You can specify sheet as well, just append `&sheet=SHEETNAME` at the end of the `URL`.