# Google Apps Dad Joke Script - JSON parse error "Unexpected token: < "

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, fetch-api

I'm trying to pull a joke from the [dad joke API](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api) using [this GAS JSON guide](https://googleappscripting.com/json/) yet am running into a parse error when I try to get a JSON object.

The error happens when I call `JSON.parse(dadJokeText);`

The first fix I've tried was [publishing my app for public, anonymous use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725424/content-service-for-google-apps-script-returning-html-instead-of-json) (may have been an auth issue), that didn't work.

Tried reformatting my code using [this suggestion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88362/import-json-to-google-sheet-using-google-apps-script), still same error.

I do not have any experience using JSON, sorry that this is a dupe post, haven't had success trying to learn from the other questions.

Thanks in advance

```
function getJoke() {
  var url = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";
  var options = {
    "contentType" : "application/json" 
  }

  // make a GET request to the dad joke API
  var dadJokeJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var dadJokeText = dadJokeJSON.getContentText();
  var dadJokeObject = JSON.parse(dadJokeText);
  var joke = dadJokeObject.value['joke'];



  // log the joke that you retrieved
  Logger.log(joke);

}
```

edit: this is the value of `dadJokeText`, looks like the HTML for the page

```
[18-12-10 12:06:11:690 EST] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="The largest collection of dad jokes on the internet" />
<meta name="author" content="C653 Labs" />
<meta name="keywords" content="dad,joke,funny,slack,alexa" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="icanhazdadjoke" />
<meta property="og:title" content="icanhazdadjoke" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Why should you never trust a pig with a secret? Because it's bound to squeal." />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/static/smile.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@icanhazdadjoke">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="icanhzdadjoke">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Why should you never trust a pig with a secret? Because it's bound to squeal.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/static/smile.png">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd">
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/j/7UnjNRfapzd/amp">
<title>icanhazdadjoke</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/static/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#1fc8db">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/static/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dist/style.css?55f4ea12">
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/",
        "name": "icanhazdadjoke",
        "description": "The largest collection of dad jokes on the internet",
        "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "SearchAction",
          "target": "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term={search_term_string}",
          "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
      }
    </script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/",
        "logo": "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/static/smile.png",
        "name": "icanhazdadjoke",
        "description": "The largest collection of dad jokes on the internet",
        "email": "support@icanhazdadjoke.com"
      }
    </script>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3200991035275362", enable_page_level_ads: true});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav has-shadow">
<div class="container">
<div class="nav-left">
<a class="nav-item is-brand" href="/">
<img src="/static/smile.svg" alt="icanhazdadjoke logo" />
<span class="subtitle pushhalf--left">
icanhazdadjoke
</span>
</a>
</div>
<span id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</span>
<div id="nav-menu" class="nav-right nav-menu">
<a class="nav-item is-tab" href="/">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-random"></i>
</span>
<span class="pushquarter--left">
Random joke
</span>
</a>
<a class="nav-item is-tab" href="/search">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</span>
<span class="pushquarter--left">
Search jokes
</span>
</a>
<a class="nav-item is-tab" href="/submit">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</span>
<span class="pushquarter--left">
Submit new joke
</span>
</a>
<div class="nav-item">
<a href="/slack-add" style="height:40px; max-width:139px">
<img alt="Add to Slack" height="40" width="139" src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" style="width:139px; height:40px; max-height: 40px" srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="nav-item">
<a class="button" target="_blank" href="https://www.amazon.com/Brett-Langdon-icanhazdadjoke/dp/B01N6CQ3NZ/" style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #5ebfe4; border-radius: 6px; font-weight: 500; height:40px; width:139px; max-width:139px">
<img src="/static/alexa-logo.png" style="margin-left: -0.5em;">
Add to <strong style="margin-left: 0.25em">Alexa</strong>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<section class="section">
<div class="container">
<div class="level">
<div class="level-left">
<div class="content level-item">
<h1>Random dad joke:</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="level-right">
<a class="button is-primary level-item" href="/">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-random"></i>
</span>
<span>
New joke
</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-content">
<p class="subtitle">Why should you never trust a pig with a secret? Because it's bound to squeal.</p>
</div>
<footer class="card-footer">
<a class="card-footer-item" href="/j/7UnjNRfapzd">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
</span>
<span class="pushquarter--left">
Permalink
</span>
</a>
<a class="card-footer-item" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://icanhazdadjoke.com%2Fj%2F7UnjNRfapzd%2Famp&text=Check+out+this+%23dadjoke&via=icanhazdadjoke">
<span class="icon is-small">
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</span>
<span class="pushquarter--left">
Share on Twitter
</span>
</a>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content pushwhole--top">
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3200991035275362" data-ad-slot="5324903139" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
</div>
<script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
</div>
</section>
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="columns">
<div class="column is-5">
<div class="content">
<p>
<strong>icanhazdadjoke.com</strong> by <a href="https://c653labs.com/">C653 Labs</a>.
</p>
<p>
<i>icanhazdadjoke.com</i> is the largest selection of dad jokes on the internet.
Now supporting many different integrations to ensure you can access the dad jokes that you need wherever you are.
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column is-3"></div>
<div class="column is-2">
<aside class="menu">
<ul class="menu-list">
<li><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#94e7e1e4e4fbe6e0d4fdf7f5fafcf5eef0f5f0fefbfff1baf7fbf9" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/icanhazdadjoke" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="https://slack.com/apps/A214NCJF2-icanhazdadjoke" target="_blank">Slack app</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Brett-Langdon-icanhazdadjoke/dp/B01N6CQ3NZ/" target="_blank">Alexa skill</a></li>
<li><a href="https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=467365247921946626&permissions=0&scope=bot" target="_blank">Discord bot</a></li>
<li><a href="https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.icanhazdadjoke/cloud/overview" target="_blank">HipChat plugin</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twistapp.com/integrations/install/20_901fa9d3df5b8784d3ddc56e" target="_blank">Twist integration</a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
</div>
<div class="column is-2">
<aside class="menu">
<ul class="menu-list">
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/api">API</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Random joke</a></li>
<li><a href="/search">Search jokes</a></li>
<li><a href="/submit">Submit new joke</a></li>
</ul>
<
```

Comment: Please add what the value of `dadJokeText ` is.

Comment: edited, added the logger output

Comment: If that is the true value of `dadJokeText` it is not `JSON`

Comment: does that mean my code has an issue? or that the API is broken? what do you think I should do to investigate this?

Comment: I would read the documentation on the API and find out the return type of each API call and code accordingly. Also, since this seems to be serving up an entire web page, I think you may be making the incorrect API call, if all you are trying to do is get a joke returned from the API.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere in your "fetch" call do you set the "Accept" header to "application/json" as [required by the API](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api) in order to get the response formatted as JSON.

You do set a variable called `options` in your code, but as far as I can see you never use it for anything. And in any case it sets the wrong header - needs to be "Accept", not "ContentType" - actually it should be "Content-Type" to be correct, but even then, Content type tells the server what type of data you are *sending*, not what kind you would *like back in return*.

I would expect you need to make your request like this:

```
var url = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";
var options = { 
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/json" 
  }
};

// make a GET request to the dad joke API
var dadJokeJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch for documentation on the Fetch API in JavaScript