# App Script sends 405 response when trying to send a POST request

Tags: google-apps-script, axios, cors, http-status-code-405

I have published an app script publicly (Anyone, even anonymous) with a doPost method as follow,

```
 function doPost(e){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var length = e.contentLength;
    var body = e.postData.contents;
    var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    sheet.appendRow([jsonData.title, length]);
    var MyResponse = "works";
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(MyResponse).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

When I sent a Post request with a JSON object with Advanced Rest Client it all works and return a 200 OK response. But when I try to send a post request with the react axios from a locally hosted react app it sends a 405 Response.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzyc2CG9xLM-igL3zuslSmNY2GewL5seTWpMpDIQr_5eCod7_U/exec. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I have enabled cross origin resource sharing in the  browser as well. The function that sends the POST request is as follow,

```
axios({
          method:'post',
          url:'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzyc2CG9xLM-igL3zuslSmNY2GewL5seTWpMpDIQr_5eCod7_U/exec',
          data: {
            "title": 'Fred',
            "lastName": 'Flintstone'
          }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

Comment: try `POST` instead of `post`, that solved a similar problem for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You missed the important part:

> **Response for preflight** has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Your browser is making a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), which uses the [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) HTTP method. This is to check whether the server will allow the `POST` request – the `405` status code is sent in the response to the `OPTIONS` request, not your `POST` request.

> A CORS preflight request is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/CORS) request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood. [<sup>Source</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)
>
> ---
>
> Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), or for [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) usage with certain [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method. [<sup>Source</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Functional_overview)
>
> ---
>
> Some requests don’t trigger a [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Those are called "simple requests" in this article [...] [<sup>Source</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests)
>   <sub>This article section details the conditions a request has to meet to be considered a "simple request".</sub>
>
> ---
>
> [...] "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data. [<sup>Source</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)
>   <sub>This article section details the conditions which cause a request to be preflighted.</sub>

In this case, the following is causing the request to be preflighted:

> [...] **if** the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header has a value other than the following:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
> - `multipart/form-data`
> - `text/plain`

The value for the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json;charset=utf-8` by axios. Using `text/plain;charset=utf-8` or `text/plain` fixes the problem:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzyc2CG9xLM-igL3zuslSmNY2GewL5seTWpMpDIQr_5eCod7_U/exec',
    data: {
        title: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone',
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
    },
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: "the 405 status code is sent in the response to the OPTIONS request, not your POST request" this part I knew, but I was under the impression that browsers send pre-flights for all post requests. "if the Content-Type header has a value other than the following:..." this part I didn't know. Although I manged a work around , which I can't exactly remember right now, I would mark this as the answer without testing since  what I was looking for was also avoiding the prefilght. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: This helped me avoiding preflight (and thus 405), thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 3):

Another way for someone who has this problem in the future:

*(in my case, using `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'` doesn't work)*

According to this doc https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Instead of using `text/plain;charset=utf-8` as the accepted answer, you can use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('qs')

const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzyc2CG9xLM-igL3zuslSmNY2GewL5seTWpMpDIQr_5eCod7_U/exec'

const data = {
        "title": 'Fred',
        "lastName": 'Flintstone'
}

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url
}

axios(options)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to return JSON data. It is possible that you need to return JSONP to a request from a browser, but here is what I think you need to do:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({message: MyResponse})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

If that doesn't work, it is probably that you need to return JSONP to run in the browser. Here is some documentation to help you out: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages

Comment: One other thing... make sure you deploy as a new version. Don't just update.

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK YOUR API REQUEST METHOD AND API ENDPOINT METHOD NAMES!**

I was sending a POST request to a GET endpoint. This returns HTTP 405 error.