# Python Flask Caching 401 POST and Applying to next request

Tags: python, rest, flask, backend

I have a Python flask backend that returns JSON. Every time I make a POST request that returns a 401 (because tokens have expired) it then prepends the JSON body data to the next request, which causes a 405 method not allowed because as you can see, the data is showing where the method should be. This is the same issue as [this post for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837615/auth-refresh-token-not-working-when-the-orgin-request-is-a-post-method)

This is the log from my local:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2022 08:17:01] "POST /stsatellites/filter HTTP/1.1" 401 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2022 08:17:29] "OPTIONS /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2022 08:17:29] "{"filters":[{"field":"NORAD_CAT_ID","op":"eq","value":25165}]}POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Here are screenshots of the requests, as you can see that filter data originated on the first request which got the 401 response.
[Filter POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tjkQ.png)
[Filter POST Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVOV0.png)

Following Login request:
[Login POST Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmXt.png)
[Login POST Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyFS.png)

We have a workaround in place which resolves this issue but it's a band-aid that I would like to remove. For some reason the `request.get_data` method fixes the caching issue.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request_func(response):
    if response.status == "401 UNAUTHORIZED": 
        request.get_data(cache=False)
    return response
```

Comment: What brought Django in here ?

Comment: I have no idea other than the tag and link to the other issue.

Comment: I ran across the same issue in local development of a flask app