# Connecting a Hello sign API to apps script project

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, http-status-code-405, post-redirect-get, hellosign-api

I want to Create a new API app usin Google Apps script and Hello sign API

I have specified the redirect URL as https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyKw3oLmpqINGsDml281iUbxBboKn950dqVFXNibMfLurxYcRPf/exec and the screenshot is shown below

Also, the code of the apps script file is

```
function doPost(e) {
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello API Event Received.");
}
```

The documentation says: https://app.hellosign.com/api/eventsAndCallbacksWalkthrough

I get error message as shown like here[image]

Illustation image here[image]

Answer (score 2):

`405`([http-status-code-405](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-405)) is "method not allowed", where a incorrect method is used. In this case, [`ContentService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects) uses a specific pattern of redirection ([post-redirect-get](/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get)[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)), where the `POST` request to `script.google.com` is redirected([`302`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#Temporary_redirections)) to a one time url at `script.googleusercontent.com`, to which a `GET` request should be made.

[`302` specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) did not intend the method to change from `POST` to `GET`, but this pattern is very common in the web. But, [hellosign-api](/questions/tagged/hellosign-api) seems to make another `POST`  request to the one time redirected url at `script.googleusercontent.com`. There isn't much you could do from apps script to change this behavior. It is possible to change to `HtmlService` to avoid the redirection, but Hellosign specifically requires you to provide a specific text content as response: `Hello API Event Received`. This isn't possible with `HtmlService`.

You could [make a feature request/bug fix request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) to Google to change redirect status to [303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303), where method change to `GET` is explicitly specified. Or Make a request to Hellosign to follow [`302`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) redirects with `GET` request, as that is the most common way, things are done in the web.

#### References:

- [Curl redirect preferred method -L](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L)
- [`ContentService` Redirect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects)
- [Post redirect get wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)
- [RFC7231 § 6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)
- [RFC7231 § 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at our backend logs, we see that your callback URL is not allowing our POST call to be granted to fetch "Hello API Event Received" response. This can be due to they way your [callback handler is set up][1].

Would you mind taking a look at this similar ask and they way they tackled the POST/`Allow` header field and let us know how it goes by emailing at apisupport@hellosign.com?

[App Script sends 405 response when trying to send a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910180/app-script-sends-405-response-when-trying-to-send-a-post-request/46836144)

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405#:~:text=The%20HyperText%20Transfer%20Protocol%20(HTTP,supported%20by%20the%20target%20resource.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63676056/)