# How to use a Web App URI as a webhook callback URI?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, servicem8

I'm trying to create a Web App with a `doPost()` method. This POST method should receive and answer the POST request from the Webhook with a Challenge, and receive the corresponding JSON that will be placed in a Google Sheet.

Current code looks something like this:

```
function doPost(e) {
   // Try to answer the challenge
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).challenge);

   // . . . do something else here with the JSON . . .
}
```

When I do the POST from Postman its returning this error:

```
{
"success": false,
    "message": "Invalid callback challenge key returned",
    "detail": "Expected '[Challenge_ID_Here]' but received '[Google HTML Code Here]'"
}
```

I set up a callback_url with https://webhook.site/ and got a successful response from it when setting it up with `request.form.challenge`, but I don't know how to answer with the challenge correctly with the Web App.

---

I successfully got the `doPost()` method to successfully parse the Challenge ID and print it in the Google Sheet.

I'm now trying to respond back with the ID like this:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.parse(result).parameters.challenge).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Still getting an unsuccessful response, but it is now redirecting to a `script.googleusercontent.com` domain, saying that the file has moved there. I enabled following redirects in Postman.

My POST request from Postman looks something like this:

```
curl --location --request POST '[Webhook_Subscriptions_URL]' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [Token_ID]' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'object=myObject' \
--data-urlencode 'fields=myField1, myField2' \
--data-urlencode 'callback_url=https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]/exec'
```

Comment: Needs debugging details/logs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/

Comment: @TheMaster I can't debug from the Google Apps Script side if its not receiving anything. I did try making curl POST requests from the command line with some JSON, and got it to print into the Google Sheet. But from the Webhook I'm not receiving anything.

Comment: You should mention that in your question. Still need debugging details like: How is the webapp published? Execute as? Access?etc

Comment: @TheMaster its published inside GAS as Web App. Its executed with my user but anyone can access it, even anonymous. App URL is just how Google sets up every web app: https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID_HERE]/exec

Comment: @TheMaster its just the basic HTML that comes in the Web App: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico\"><title>Error</title><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:20px\"><div><img alt=\"Google Apps Script\" src=\"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png\"></div><div style=\"text-align:center;font-family:monospace;m`

Comment: What is the error shown in that html page?

Comment: None. There is no error. That is returned in the POST request.

Comment: The html shows the error. Could you just [edit] in the full html?

Comment: @TheMaster thats the entire HTML returned in the request...

Comment: The entire html should start  and end with `<html>...</html>`. Use ``curl`` if postman doesn't show full html. The top snippet you show clearly shows that that is a error page: `"><title>Error</title><`

Comment: @TheMaster Just ran the command over console and got the same result.

Comment: Are you saying it ended with `....-family:monospace;m` as shown in your previous comment ?

Comment: You still haven't shown me the error. What exactly is the error?

Comment: @TheMaster The error occurs when the WebApp doesn't answer back correctly with the Challenge ID. Like the error I show in my original post.

Comment: Like I said, I need to see the full html page. It is showing a "Error" html page. This could mean a lot of things. It could be a Google login page, file not found or any other error. At least try to get the full page. Also, Another way would be to check view>  stackdriver logging. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222283/discussion-between-diego-and-themaster).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63676056/