# HTTP request to Google apps script from VBA keeps resulting in 405 status

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I am trying to send data through HTTP POST from an Excel/VBA script to an API I built in Google Apps script. **The Google script executes correctly, but always returns a 405 "Method not allowed" and the return value is an HTML page from Google Drive.**
When I send the same POST from Postman, I get status 200 and the return value is he one that is implemented in the Google script.

The Google apps minimal test script that I used:

```
function doPost(e) {
  
  
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Gelukt").setMimeType(MimeType.JSON);

}
```

The relevant code in VBA:

```
With objHTTP
    .Open "POST", Url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US"
    .send JsonString
End With
```

When I send the POST request to webhook.site it shows this:[image]

I tried all suggestions I could find, but nothing changes the 405!

Comment: The Content-Type is different in your webhook example. Does it work in VBA if you try `"content-type", "application/json"`?

Comment: Seems related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878421/google-apps-script-return-405-for-post-request   If you use GET does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else needs it, use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` instead of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`. The problem is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886316/13607876

In general, `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` cannot handle redirects coming from GAS using a GET request.
`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` sends a POST request, GAS processes it and sends back a link to redirect using a GET request. However, `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` does the redirect using a POST request and GAS rejects it with a "Method not allowed" error.
`WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` does the redirect using a GET request, so there is no problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added asummary of the information at the end of the link so the answer is self-contained