# CORS block: WebApp POST to Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am getting an error due to CORS policy. It seems a common issue. I have read other questions and tried some of their solutions, but it still does not work.

My app does the following: 
1- GET a list of values from a google sheet and show them in a drop down list in a web app (still using script.google.com)
2- POST the value that the user select in the drop down list from the web app to the sheet.

1 (GET) was working fine with no issues. When I added 2 (POST), it gave me the CORS error for the POST call. The GET seems fine.

Here is the code for POST:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var value = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zbvy1x_DsBlcwK4FdjoY4m0MFvS_tYZlGtKvD36fDyk');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  sh.getRange(92, 2).setValue(value);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({message: "ok"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

with HTML file:

```
<script>
function listQ() {
    const index = this.selectedIndex;
    if (index > 0) {
      const e = document.getElementById("sel1");
      const value = e.options[index].value;
      const url = "https://script.google.com/a/google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHX7cthji076OrqfY9ZpGa7jNDxKHUMf_ib7Ekmoo0Ir5DQF1Y/exec";  
      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({index: index, value: value}),
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }
document.getElementById("sel1").addEventListener("change",listQ);
</script>
```

The GET part is fine, so no need to add the code here.

I have tried to change POST with PUT as suggested here: [Change Google Sheet data based on user selection in Google Site (Web App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688190/change-google-sheet-data-based-on-user-selection-in-google-site-web-app/61689738?noredirect=1#comment109146146_61689738) but it gave the same error.

I have also read this link, but mine is a POST request, not GET and I am not sure how to apply it to my case: [CORS authorization on google sheets API requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546969/cors-authorization-on-google-sheets-api-requests)

FYI The "origin" in the CORS error message is ...googleusercontent.com

**UPDATE:** I have also tried this: [Google Apps Script cross-domain requests stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525860/google-apps-script-cross-domain-requests-stopped-working)

I think I should implement that solution, but when I tried to add those mods in my code and it did not work. Probably I am adding the mods incorrectly since I am not 100% sure what I am doing. I get the error that the call back function is not defined. Here is what I did:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var callback = e.parameter.callback;
  var value = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ROvDcIQ8JCGvvLvCvTKIqSor530Uj9ZJv-n6hQ761XA');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  sh.getRange(92, 2).setValue(value);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(callback+'('+JSON.stringify({message: "ok"})+')').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

and in HTML side, I just modified the URL:

```
const url = "https://script.google.com/a/google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHX7cthji076OrqfY9ZpGa7jNDxKHUMf_ib7Ekmoo0Ir5DQF1Y/exec?offset="+offset+"&baseDate="+baseDate+"&callback=?";
```

Comment: Why not just use `google.script.run`?

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I am very new to google app script and javascript.

Comment: See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In order to correctly replicate and understand about your situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? And I cannot understand about `I have tried to change POST with PUT as suggested here:`. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apps Script Web Apps, in order to access server-side functions from your current project, you don't need to make a `GET` or `POST` request to the Web App URL. You just need to use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

In your exact case, you could do the following:

```js
function listQ() {
  const index = this.selectedIndex;
  if (index > 0) {
    const e = document.getElementById("sel1");
    const value = e.options[index].value;
    const body = { index: index, value: value };
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yourCallback).yourServerSideFunc(body);
  }
}

function yourCallBack(response) {
  // Whatever you want to do with the data retrieved from server-side
}
```

In the code above, the client-side function calls a server side function called `yourServerSideFunc` via `google.script.run`. If the server-side function returns successfully, a callback function is called (function `yourCallback`), whose purpose is to handle the data returned from the server (a callback is needed since, on its own, the function called by `google.script.run` returns void). This callback function receives the content returned by the server-side function as an argument.

And in the server-side, no need to use `doPost`, since you would not be making a `POST` request:

```js
function yourServerSideFunc(body) {
  var value = body["value"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zbvy1x_DsBlcwK4FdjoY4m0MFvS_tYZlGtKvD36fDyk');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  sh.getRange(92, 2).setValue(value);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({message: "ok"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);  
}
```

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am sorry about my lack of understanding, I am new to this. You explained that the callback function returns void, but it calls the yourServerSideFunc(body)? which should already set the values in the sheet? 
Basically what I want to do with the data retrieved from the drop down list is specified in the yourServerSideFunc(body) so not sure what to do with the yourCallBack(response). FYI there is a typo in your answer (yourCallback vs yourCallBack) and I am getting an error: yourServerSideFunc is not defined at yourCallBack.

Comment: Actually it works! I was getting that error, but was still setting the right value in the sheet. Now I am leaving the yourCallBack(response) blank and it dies not give any error message. It works fine!